# multiple sqlite databases creation

Tags: python, django, sqlite, mongoengine

I have Django application that using MongoDB with Mongoengine. I need to create several sqlite databases. Every SQLite database associated with one of all documents of some MondoDB collection (for example MainDocument). SQLite duplicate some collections documents that depend on MainDocument with one-to-many relation. So... Number of documents on MainDocument is 1074! I need to create 1074 sqlite databases with different names.
I fill one default sqlite database with django orm then copy it with other name, then truncate all tables and start again for another document. It takes a long time. How to do it faster?
It's possible with django orm without configuring 1074 database routers?

I've tried use ramfs, but it still so slowly.

Comment: Can you explain why?  Sounds like the wrong approach from the outside.

Comment: What is the _actual problem you are trying to solve_.

Comment: @Ross, Database on site using MongoDB. Customer wants create mobile application on Android and iOS for site, that require SQLite for each client location. It's sounds crazy, I know. But I have this task and I don't care how it works on mobile devices